Flyway compatibility with IntelliJ community edition
Does flyway init migration from JPA buddy extension works for IntelliJ community edition?
I am not able to access, it asks for the ultimate version of IntelliJ.
Is it possible to implement data versioning using flyway init using the community edition?

its only for ultimate.
JPA Buddy is a free IntelliJ plugin. There are a few features available only for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition subscribers.....
